# Is it safe to use Ethernet link from linux on virtual box, and USB modem from host windows XP simultaneously?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, ethernet, modem

Environment:

- Win XP SP3 connected to the internet from a USB modem on an 845GBV board
- Win 7 x64 with an on-board realtek chip

What I want to try:

- Setup a NIC on the 845 GBV board
- Use the slackware installed on virtual box to be the gateway for my second box from the NIC card
- Subsequently make this a 2-node cluster (perhaps beowulf/knoppix just to play with BOINC to begin with) running Slack on the other box (that currently runs Win 7 x64)

My concern:

- Is this feasible?
- Could this arrangement Win XP(USB) > Slack (Virtual box/Ethernet) > Windows 7 x64 (Ethernet) damage my hardware?

Comment: Huh?  You've lost me somewhere.  Could you perhaps draw a diagram?

Comment: @Iszi: 
1) I want to try my hand at a cluster
2) Have only 2 machines in hand both of which run Windows
3) One of these I intend to provide with another hard-drive which shall run linux exclusively. The other must run linux on virtual box.

Can I tunnel from linux to linux on virtual-box , and then use the internet connection on the virtual box host?